# TypeError missing 3 required positional arguments

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

I have a tkinter button invoking the command "nadirpatch" when pressed. When I press the button, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: nadirpatch() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'photoSphere', 'nadir', and 'photospherePath'
```

Here is my code for "nadirpatch": (the variables have already been defined)

```
def nadirpatch(photoSphere, nadir, photospherePath):
    for photospherePath in photospherePath:
        photoSphere = Image.open(photospherePath) 
        nadir = Image.open(nadirPath)
        nadir = nadir.resize((photoSphere.size), resample=0)
        photoSphere.paste(nadir, (0, 0), nadir) 
        photoSphere.save((stitchedPath+"/patchedsphere"+(str(fileNum+1))+".jpeg"), "JPEG")
        fileNum +=1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass arguments in the Button definition as shown below:

```
# Sample code
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command= lambda: nadirpatch(photoSphere, nadir, photospherePath))
```